# AWS lightsail cronjob isn't firing

Tags: node.js, cron

Very simple cron task not working.

When tested in the terminal it works fine, but doesnt fire as a crontab. Im using AWS lightsail instance.

test.js code

```
console.log("working");
```

crontab

```
* * * * * /home/bitnami/stack/nodejs/bin/node /home/bitnami/cron_files/test.js
```

Comment: are requiring modules absolute or relative in test.js?

Comment: there are no required modules in test.js. only console.log.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with console.log not with the crontab, which is working

Comment: you may be not redirecting output to a cronjob.

Comment: * * * * * /home/bitnami/stack/nodejs/bin/node /home/bitnami/cron_files/test.js
 > //home/bitnami/cron_files/test_log.put

Comment: That worked perfectly, although I had to take away the extra backslash